# Change color of the td cell based on the value in database

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, django

Hi am working on a Django powered website. I have an html table which returns ids of particular records. My goal is to change the td cell color based on the values. The following is my html

```
                   {% for l in all_items %}

                                <td style="text-align: center"
                                    id="{{m.id}}_{{m.set}}">
                                </td>

                    {% endfor %}
```

and am passing values to the id using JavaScript as below:

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
    {% for a in all_results %}
            $('#{{a.id}}_{{a.set}}').html('{{a.id}}');
    {% endfor %}
});
</script>
```

One of my css(based on status):

```
.completed{
    background-color: #53A36E;
}
```

Since its a for loop in html for all items, each item is returning different values (ids and there is another column which am not displaying is status). The colour of the td cell (contains id) will change based on the status. How can I make it happen? Thanks in advance guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have a `CharField` named `status` field in your model and it can have the value `"completed"`, you can write:

```
<td style="text-align: center"
    class="{{ m.status }}"
    id="{{ m.id }}_{{ m.set }}">
</td>
```

For the cells where `m.status` is `"completed"` the background colour would be `#53A36E`.

If you need to set the class from Javascript, you can use the following:

```
{% for a in all_results %}
        $('#{{ a.id }}_{{ a.set }}').html('{{ a.id }}');
        $('#{{ a.id }}_{{ a.set }}').addClass('{{ a.status }}');
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks Selcuk. I tried that but its making the entire td to #53A36E colour, instead of the cell that have the value (id)

Comment: What do you mean by entire `td`?

Comment: whole horizontal row of the table (including those cells (td-th) with no data (no id vlaue). I want to make the single (td-th cell of that particular row) to that color. Got it Selcuk?

Comment: Then you can use the same method using JQuery, see my updated answer.

Comment: Worked. Thanks Selcuk